# Как все же правильнее обзывать разделы в URL?

Tags: url, чпу

В одном проекте у меня:

- /category
- /category/13/edit

В другом уже:

- /posts/
- /posts/13/edit

Вопрос возможно и глупый, но может есть какие-нибудь стандарты, что бы я раз и навсегда определился?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, универсальное решение:

`node` (узел)

```
/node/13/edit
```

Comment: То есть предлагаете не использовать `s` в окончаниях?

Comment: А зачем? кому оно нужно?